# Grok logstash message without patterns file

Tags: design-patterns, logstash

I would like to know if it's possible to grok message with logstash without using an external patterns file and directly write my pattern in my config:

For example, now it's works like this :

```
input { 
     stdin{     
    }   
}
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "./patterns"
        match => ["message","%{PATTERNFILE:test}"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}

}
```

I have a file in a patterns folder with the following content :

```
PATTERNFILE .*
```

But I would like to directly write my pattern in the filter like this :

```
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "./patterns"
        match => ["message","%{.*:test}"]
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

To directly write a pattern in the config file without having an exernal patterns file, the solution is:

```
filter {grok{ match => ["message", "(?<test>.*)"]}}
```

The method is described at http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok in section "Custom patterns"

Answer (score 1):

For using **patterns_dir** you should use full path **/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns/dns_domain** for example:

```
  grok {
    patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns/dns_domain"
    match => { "Unparsed DNS Domain" => "%{BRACKETS:b1}%{META_INF:m1}" }
  }
```

Where **dns_domain** file contains custom patterns. for example:

```
  BRACKETS \(\d+\)
  META_INF [0-9A-Za-z\s\-_]+
  ~                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  ~
```

Answer (score 0):

match => { "message" => "%{PATTERNFILE}" }